# Gradle : Unresolved compilation problem: log cannot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, lombok

I am stuck with a very weird problem.

I have a spring boot project managed by ***gradle***, which has **no** errors in workspace. But when I run the spring boot application from eclipse (right clicking on @SpringBootApplication file and doing run as java application), it throws the following error:

```
Application startup failed
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    log cannot be resolved
```

But the weird thing is, when I run the same application from command line using `./gradle run` it works perfectly fine.

Also I have imported few other gradle projects which makes use of ***lombok*** and they works perfectly fine from eclipse, so you can assume that lombok is set up perfectly in eclipse.

Just to give you some info, I have already tried the following steps

- Refreshed gradle project
- cleaned the project and restarted the eclipse
- I already have lombok dependency in gradle
- Lombok setup is done and other project are able to pick lombok annotations
- Downloaded new eclipse version, problem stills exists

I am not able to figure out the problem. Please help!!.

Comment: Wondering if you have Lombok as implementation dependency or providedCompile. Did you try changing to implementation ?

Comment: Adding your build.gradle or build.gradle.kts can throw more light into it.

Comment: @Ashish Application works fine when I do ./gradle run from command line. So you can assume lombok is set up perfectly fine in project